# Oracle query to keep looking until value is not 0 anymore

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am using Oracle 11.
I have 2 tables

TblA with columns id, entity_id and effective_date.
TblADetail with columns id and value.
If Value = 0 for the effective date, I want to keep looking for the next effective date until I found value <> 0 anymore.

The below query only look for value on 3/10/21.
If value = 0, I want to look for value on 3/11/21. If that's not 0, I want to stop.
But, if that's 0, I want to look for value on 3/12/21. If that's not 0, I want to stop.
But, if that's 0, I want to keep looking until value is not 0.
How can I do that ?

```
SELECT SUM(pd.VALUE) 
FROM TblA p,TblADetail pd
WHERE     p.id = pd.id
AND p.effective_date = to_date('03/10/2021','MM/DD/YYYY')
AND TRIM (p.entity_id) = 123
```

Sample data:
TblA

```
id   entity_id effective_date
1    123       3/10/21
2    123       3/11/21
3    123       3/12/21
```

TblADetail

```
id value
1  -136
1  136
2  2000
3  3000
```

In the above data, for entity_id 123, starting from effective_date 3/10/21, I would like to to return value 2000 (from TblADetail) effective_date 3/11/21.

So, starting from a certain date, I want the results from the minimum date that has non-zero values.

Thank you.

Comment: Sample data and expected output would be hugely helpful here.  You're joining two tables and doing a `sum`, for example, so presumably you can return multiple rows.  Do you need two tables?  Or could you demonstrate the problem with 1 and simplify the query?  What if 1 of n rows you are summing has a `value` of 0?  What if none of the individual `value` rows are 0 but the `sum` is 0?

Comment: Are you saying you want the results from the minimum date that has non-zero values, where the date is at least a particular date?

Comment: I do need 2 tables, because the effective date is from TblA, and the Value is from TblADetail. Individual value rows can be 0, but I am looking for when the sum is 0.
I added an example in my original post. Yes, starting from a certain date, I want the results from the minimum date that has non-zero values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do what you need to do by grouping the sum on the effective date, and using the `MIN` analytic function to find the earliest date. Once you've done that, you simply need to select the date that matches the earliest date.

E.g.:

```
with     tbla as (select 1 id, ' 123' entity_id, to_date('10/03/2021', 'dd/mm/yyyy') effective_date from dual union all
                  select 2 id, ' 123' entity_id, to_date('11/03/2021', 'dd/mm/yyyy') effective_date from dual union all
                  select 3 id, ' 123' entity_id, to_date('12/03/2021', 'dd/mm/yyyy') effective_date from dual),
  tbla_detail as (select 1 id, -136 value from dual union all
                  select 1 id,  136 value from dual union all
                  select 2 id, 2000 value from dual union all
                  select 3 id, 3000 value from dual),
      results as (select a.effective_date,
                         sum(ad.value) sum_value,
                         min(case when sum(ad.value) != 0 then a.effective_date end) over () min_effective_date
                  from   tbla a
                         inner join tbla_detail ad on a.id = ad.id
                  where  a.effective_date >= to_date('10/03/2021', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
                  and    trim(a.entity_id) = '123'
                  group by a.effective_date)
select sum_value
from   results
where  effective_date = min_effective_date;

 SUM_VALUE
----------
      2000
```

Answer (score 0):

Straightforward; read comments within code. Sample data in lines #1 - 13, query begins at line #14.

```
SQL> with
  2  -- sample data
  3  tbla (id, entity_id, effective_date) as
  4    (select 1, 123, date '2021-03-10' from dual union all
  5     select 2, 123, date '2021-03-11' from dual union all
  6     select 3, 123, date '2021-03-12' from dual
  7    ),
  8  tblb (id, value) as
  9    (select 1, -136 from dual union all
 10     select 1,  136 from dual union all
 11     select 2, 2000 from dual union all
 12     select 3, 3000 from dual
 13    ),
 14  tblb_temp as
 15    -- simple grouping per ID
 16    (select id, sum(value) value
 17     from tblb
 18     group by id
 19    )
 20  -- return TBLA values whose ID equals TBLB_TEMP's minimum ID
 21  -- whose value isn't zero
 22  select a.id, a.entity_id, a.effective_date
 23  from tbla a
 24  where a.id = (select min(b.id)
 25                from tblb_temp b
 26                where b.value > 0
 27               );

        ID  ENTITY_ID EFFECTIVE_
---------- ---------- ----------
         2        123 03/11/2021

SQL>
```

Comment: Hi, it needs the sum(value) of the minimum effective_date (after a certain date), not  minimum id. So, in my example above, I need the sum(value) that's not 0 of date closest to 3/10/21. In this case 3/11/21 sum(value) is not 0

Comment: Thank you Boneist. Your query works, but how about if all values are 0 ? Your query will return nothing in this case. How can it return 0 when all values are 0 ? Thank you